# Make Clappr video player full screen on Tizen OS

Tags: javascript, tizen

I'm building a simple app for Tizen OS Smart TVs.

The app has to contain one main element: a video player.

I've already build it for WebOS and it works fine, while I noticed that in TizenOS the video player hide the "fullscreen button".

I searched in the Tized Docs end found this example:
https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/guides/w3c/supplement/fullscreen/

I tried to implement the "Toggle fullscreen video" button but it doesn't work, I hope to be near the solution...

Here's the entire code:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clappr@latest/dist/clappr.min.js"></script>
        <script type ="text/javascript" src ="main.js"> </script>
        <title>Mitology TV</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: #202020;
            }

            h1 {
                vertical-align: middle;
                text-align: center;
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }
            a   {color:white; font-weight:900;font-family:'Montserrat',sans-serif;text-decoration:solid;}
        
            #header{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;flex-direction:column;}
            #clappr: full-screen{background:black;}
            #clappr: -webkit-full-screen {background:black;}
            #clappr{ width: 100%;height: 100%;position:relative; min-height: 600px;}
            #clappr > div{ width:100%;height:100%;position: absolute;}
            #clappr > div > div.media-control.live > div.media-control-layer {
                width:85% !important;
                position: absolute;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <img src="images/MitologyTV-logo.png" style="width:200px;margin-top:120px;" />
        <h1>La musica più bella di sempre ora la vedi in faccia.</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="clappr" style="border:2px solid white;width:80vw;margin:5% auto 0% auto;"></div>
    <button id="toggleVideo">Toggle Video fullscreen</button>
<script>
 var player = new Clappr.Player({
  source:"https://64b16f23efbee.streamlock.net:443/mitologytv/mitologytv/playlist.m3u8",
    parentId: "#clappr",
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  autoPlay: true,
    //gaAccount: 'UA-44332211-1',
  //gaTrackerName: 'MyPlayerInstance'
  });
</script>
<script>
    function toggleFullScreenHandler(e, target) {
        var target = document.getElementById(target);
        /* Check whether in fullscreen mode */
        if (document.webkitIsFullScreen) {
            /* Cancel the fullscreen mode */
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        } else {
            /* Switch on the fullscreen mode */
            target.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('toggleVideo').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        toggleFullScreenHandler(e, 'clappr');
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        toggleFullScreenHandler(e);
    }, false);
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Many thanks for whoever will answer to this thread

Initially I tried to make the control buttons of the video player smaller, thinking that the fullscreen button was cut out for some reason -> found that it has been disabled.

Found the Tizen documentation but can't implement it correctly:
At this point the aim is to add a button under the video player to make it fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

These changes should add a "Toggle Fullscreen" button below your video player, allowing users to toggle fullscreen mode when clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clappr@latest/dist/clappr.min.js"></script>
        <title>Mitology TV</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: #202020;
            }
    
            h1 {
                vertical-align: middle;
                text-align: center;
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }
    
            a {
                color: white;
                font-weight: 900;
                font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
                text-decoration: solid;
            }
    
            #header {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
    
            #clappr:full-screen {
                background: black;
            }
    
            #clappr:-webkit-full-screen {
                background: black;
            }
    
            #clappr {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position: relative;
                min-height: 600px;
            }
    
            #clappr > div {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
            }
    
            #clappr > div > div.media-control.live > div.media-control-layer {
                width: 85% !important;
                position: absolute;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                text-align: center;
            }
    
            #toggleFullscreen {
                display: block;
                margin: 10px auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <img src="images/MitologyTV-logo.png" style="width:200px;margin-top:120px;" />
            <h1>La musica più bella di sempre ora la vedi in faccia.</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="clappr" style="border:2px solid white;width:80vw;margin:5% auto 0% auto;"></div>
        <button id="toggleFullscreen">Toggle Fullscreen</button>
        <script>
            var player = new Clappr.Player({
                source: "https://64b16f23efbee.streamlock.net:443/mitologytv/mitologytv/playlist.m3u8",
                parentId: "#clappr",
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                autoPlay: true,
            });
        </script>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('toggleFullscreen').addEventListener('click', function() {
                toggleFullScreenHandler('clappr');
            }, false);
    
            function toggleFullScreenHandler(targetId) {
                var target = document.getElementById(targetId);
    
                if (target.requestFullscreen) {
                    target.requestFullscreen();
                } else if (target.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                    target.mozRequestFullScreen();
                } else if (target.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                    target.webkitRequestFullscreen();
                } else if (target.msRequestFullscreen) {
                    target.msRequestFullscreen();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi Aamir, your code seems to work in Chrome but not in the Tizen simulator.
I'll try to test the app directly on my Samsung smart TV to see if it works this afternoon.
Many thanks for your support

Comment: Ok it works almost perfectly.
Now by clicking the toggleFullscreen button the view is fullscreen but with wide black bands on all the sides (like it is set a padding value to the player).

If I launch the html file on my laptop's browser, it goes correctly fullscreen.

Comment: #clappr element or any of its parent containers that might be causing the black bands. Check for properties like padding, margin, or width that could be affecting the player's dimensions.

Comment: Check css it will clear the wide black bands